# How to get my browser to show changes without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, tomcat7

I have manage to set up CORS in my tomcat7 webserver to be able to get my xml file from another webapp. The problem I am facing is if I change the content of the xml file, when I refresh the browser it doesn't show the changes and I have to restart the server to see the changes.

I would like to know how I can solve it. Also, is it possible to get changes without refreshing the browser??

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/test-app/note.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're sure there's no caching going on on the serverside?

Comment: How do I check if there is caching going on??

Comment: Start by hitting ctrl-f5 to reload without caching in the browser to see if that's the problem. If it's not, check the header for the file, then see you have set up some sort of caching on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full control of the element, you can use extjs to load your excel into a grid.And it can refresh the changed part without refresh whole page.

I didn't use CORS. But you can also try access a txt file to see it's related to the cache or excel.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a get method to fetch the xml data. So when you make changes to the xml file, the browser only retrieves a cache version and not actually downloading it from the server. This behavior of the browser is pretty nasty to deal with especially in IE. However, you can easily fix this issue by appending a unique timestamp id to the url you are making request to.

Eg-

`http://localhost:8080/test-app/note.xml?timestamp=12345`

For the second part of your question, yes it is possible to fetch the changed xml data without having to refresh the page but for that, you either need to implement ajax long polling or a websocket to your application.